# Permission is not working prior iOS 10 in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, swift3

I have defined the permission of Camera and Photo library in `Info.plist` and is working fine in iOS 10 but it is not working prior iOS 10.

#### Camera Permission:

```
Privacy - Camera Usage Description : $(PRODUCT_NAME) camera use
```

#### Photo Library Permission:

```
Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description : $(PRODUCT_NAME) photo use
```

Please,suggest me something.

Comment: What happens "it is not working"?

Comment: These are the permission description required from iOS 10 & above. And are not needed in lower iOS versions

Comment: it is not asking for any permission and in the setting also it is not showing the permissions of Camera and Photo under my app

Comment: what should i do to make it work in lower version of ios?

Comment: Did your **.plist** contain ""Bundle Display Name" key and it's proper value ?

Comment: Shouldn't you ask for permission too (`AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess`/`PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization`)?

Comment: Are you testing it on Simulator ?

Comment: no i am testing in an actual device

Comment: my .pList contains the "Bundle Display Name" but the key does not have any value

Comment: set '$(PRODUCT_NAME)' to "Bundle Display Name" in plist and check

Comment: yeah it's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set '$(PRODUCT_NAME)' to "Bundle Display Name" in plist is the thing that worked for me
```